# Ruby on Rails Resque perform paramters as hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, resque

I'm trying to write a resque worker to handle some background tasks like mass emailing.

What I'd like is for my worker to accept a hash of arguments:

```
class Worker
  @queue = :worker_queue

  def self.perform(options={})
    user_id = options[:user_id]
  end
end
```

Which I prefer over `self.perform(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, arg5)`.

Everything works in console (i.e. `Worker.perform(args)`). However, whenever I queue this into resque the arguments are undefined.

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find User with 'id'=
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction? I know that the enqueued paramters are serialized into JSON.

I just thought about it and could my problem be the symbol `:user_id` instead of `'user_id'`, since it is serialized?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's correct. The following code is the culprit

```
user_id = options[:user_id]
```

Specifically, the use of a symbol in the hash (`:user_id`) can cause the trouble because when the parameters are serialized/deserialized, the Hash you get in the Resque worker contains all the keys as strings.

You should use:

```
user_id = options["user_id"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes my suspicions were correct! When serialized to JSON, a Ruby symbol becomes a regular key string.

As soon as I replaced the previous code's symbols with `'user_id'`, everything started working!